# Calculate displayed eth price from opensea current_price in Opensea API

Tags: python, web-scraping, ethereum

I'm trying to scrape prices from Opensea website. I managed to get datas from the API, but now i'm stuck as the stated "current_price" in the datas completely differs from what is displayed on the website. for exemple : "current_price":"48070000000000000000.00000000","current_bounty":"480700000000000000","bounty_multiple":"0.01", when the price is actually 58, doesnt seem to make much sense. Hereinafter the code I use. Regards

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    import web3

    for tokenid in range(7028, 7029):
        i = str(tokenid)
        url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d/" + i + "/"

        response = requests.request("GET", url)

        print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, will the fact of starting from a json format modify the value I can already read in my print ?

Comment: yes you can. GIYF ;)

Comment: Hey just coming back to you above a small error, I hope :) I modified the file to read it as a json and it seems to work so far ! Only problem is when I try to print specifically the current_price as in the json it says the key doesnt exist when it actually does. i = str(tokenid)
    url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d/" + i
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    json_object = json.loads(response.text)
    print(json_object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that :

```
import requests

for tokenid in range(7000, 7029):
    i = str(tokenid)
    url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d/" + i + "/"
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    print(response.json()["orders"][0]["current_price"])

> output
46700000000000000000.00000000
46700000000000000000.00000000
46700000000000000000.00000000
```

Comment: That's weird as I can get the whole json file for the 10k pages i'm scraping, I thought just reading a specific data from the json wouldnt be a problem for the API, thanks a lot for your help ! Moreover as the error I get is a key error no ?

Comment: @GregoireLepasteur can you paste one example of json string you get, I might be able to help you better

Comment: The text was too long so I put it there https://textup.fr/601406xj 
I'm looking for the current_price data, I managed to dodge the key error by using json_object.get("current_price") but I still dont have any data when launching it

Comment: @GregoireLepasteur see updated answer , current price is actually is in inner levels , its a nested json